# Ubuntu 18.04, Ctrl-C not work in RealVNC and Remmina but working fine in local

Tags: ubuntu

I'm new to Ubuntu 18.04. When I use terminal or other software, `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-V`, etc. work fine for me. But if I use `RealVNC Viewer` connect to a remote Ubuntu 16.04 or Raspberry Pi, the `Ctrl-C` and `Ctrl-V` will only left there a "c" or "v" but nothing copied or pasted. Same thing happens when I use `Remmina` connect to remote Windows PC via RDP.

Any idea, suggestion, further steps, please share with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After connecting to the remote computer, press the right ctrl key to activate all key bindings. To change the host key (which you may need to do if you use the right ctrl key for other things), press the three bar icon on the top right of the remmina remote desktop client, go to preferences > keyboard and change the host key (changed mine to alt gr which I use less often than the right ctrl key)

Answer (score 0):

(for future reference)

In Remmina, to avoid the problem of Host keys (in this case the Ctrl keys) not being registered by the remote client, please make sure to disable\enable the toolbar icon "Grab all keyboard events" whenever needed. The toolbar icon should be located at either the top or sides of your remote screen connection.

Enabling said option in Remmina will cause all Host key events (Ctrl) to be sent to the remote client, hence you should be able to copy-paste on remote client.
Disabling said option in Remmina will cause all Host key events to be captured on your local machine.

Comment: Can you describe how to do this?  (And which one should the user do; *disable*  or  *enable*?) … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.